# ASP.NET MVC Bootstrap Form Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-form-helper

Hello I use country select from bootstrap form helper but how I can bind this with model? 
Normally I use

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Attribute, new { @class = "form-control col-md-2", required = "required" })
```

But here I have only div and I want pass data from select country list to model but dont know how. Anyone can help me?

```
                <div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries col-md-3" data-country="US" data-flags="true" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `data-name`/`name` attribute like:

```
<div class="bfh-selectbox bfh-countries col-md-3" data-name="Attribute" data-country="US" data-flags="true" ></div>
```